# F# Command Line File Order?

Tags: f#

Why does it seem like the order of the arguments matters for F#? It doesn't matter for C# (which uses the same compilation model). When I try this:

```
# main.fs
module Main
let main = Printer.print_repeatedly 5 "hello, world"

# printer.fs
module Printer
let print_repeatedly n str = for x in 1..n do printfn "%s" str
```

And I execute the compiler (both Microsoft's and Mono's) with main.fs preceding printer.fs, I get an error:

```
main.fs(4,12): error FS0039: The namespace or module 'Printer' is not defined
```

If I do printer.fs before main.fs on the command line, it's fine. Is there a reason the compiler requires this for F#?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In F#, the order of files passed to the compiler absolutely does matter: the F# compiler reads programs strictly left-to-right and top-to-bottom. Variables and types may only refer to those defined before them, unless you explicitly indicate a mutually recursive relationship via `and`.

If you come from C#, this may seem like a limitation at first. But you learn that in practice it is actually an incredibly effective enforcement of code organization and prevents recursive reference madness.

Note that forward references are actually a fairly modern feature of programming languages and compilers (you don't get them for "free"), if you've ever had to work with early C++ compilers you may remember the need for forward declarations to enable this (having the compiler do the work cost memory which has not always been so abundant).

Comment: Not to mention it drastically eases dependency management, which is the kryptonite of large projects.

Comment: I've worked with C++ a lot. I just found it strange considering F# seems to mostly follow C# type style compilation model except for this one little caveat.

Comment: @Jonathan - I think the extent to which F# and C# share a common compilation model they are both bound by the CLI. I can think of a few big differences between the two otherwise off the top of my head: C# supports implicit interface implementation and it is the recommended "default", F# only supports explicit interface implementation. F# doesn't support public static readonly fields while C# does. F# does not support sealing an overridden member while C# does. etc.

Comment: And the big one, which is also related to the reason F# cares about the compilation order: F# has much better type inference than C# does.

Comment: Are there any language reasons/examples that the files must be specified in a specific order and the code would behave differently if it were specified in a different order? Right now I don't understand why the compiler couldn't just scan the used files and work out the compile order itself