# F# Automatic Compilation Order

Tags: .net, f#, msbuild

Is there any way to automatically include all F# files in a directory/sub-directories for compilation? Ideally I'd like to not have to change my `.fsproj` file every time I create a new file.

I thought adding the following to my `.fsproj` file might work, but unfortunately the order the files are specified in matter.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="**\*.fs" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <Compile Remove="obj\**" />
    <EmbeddedResource Remove="obj\**" />
    <Compile Remove="bin\**" />
    <EmbeddedResource Remove="bin\**" />
</ItemGroup>
```

The best reasons for not wanting to change my `.fsproj` file that I could come up with are:

- pure laziness
- reducing merge conflicts when working with multiple branches in git

As an additional minor question, can anyone also clarify why the behaviour of F# MSBuild is that you have to specify every file in the correct order? I think it's related to preventing circular dependencies in the code base, but I don't understand why the compiler can't just collect all the files at compile time and if it detects any circular dependencies, then raise a compilation error.

Edit: I should mention I'm using .NET 7.0

Comment: This will probably help you: [Cyclic dependencies are evil](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/cyclic-dependencies/).

Comment: [This ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6823237/f-command-line-file-order) has similar issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specifying the files' order is a feature of the F# language itself, and not of any tool. You can imagine the compiler will compile in order from top to bottom, per line and per file listed in the project file. While doing so, it will only look backward to find referenced elements. This avoids circular dependencies, just to mention one of the advantages.

So no, you can't avoid listing the order. You also must resolve a merge conflict resulting from this, as it is actually a conflicting logic in your program if you have come up with different orders.

You can read more about organizing your F# source in Scott Wlaschin's excellent article on the subject: [Organizing modules in a project](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/recipe-part3/). In fact, you should go through the whole site if you haven't already.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Not what I was hoping for but guess it's just the state of the language. I understand it helps prevent circular dependencies but are there any language reasons/examples that the files must be specified in a specific order and the code would behave differently? Right now I don't understand why the compiler couldn't just scan the used files and check for circular dependencies itself. Then if it detected one, just raise a compilation error to let the user know

Comment: We want the language to be like this. It enforces a tidy organization. It's easier when we know references can only point back.

Comment: How does manually reordering files enforce tidy organization? If a tool built on top of an F# provides automatic ordering while still detecting and erroring out on cyclic references, how is that worse?

Comment: I don't understand the question. The developer obviously must determine the order of the files when references can only point back, and that order is specified in the project file. A tool can't read the developer's mind. In C# the order is not significant, so there's no need to list the files in order, or list them at all actually.